# On Update value of firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make a chat app as a learning project. when i am trying to run

```
firebase.functions.firestore
    .document('messages/lastMessage')
    .onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {

        const after = snapshot.after.data();
        console.log(after)

})
```

i am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined`

this is how i am importing firebase into my html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Instter</title>

    <script:scr="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>  
</head> 
<body>
     <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

I have tried searching everywhere but didn't found anything. please let me know if you know something about this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to run the functions in your web app. You must initialize Cloud Functions using the CLI in your project directory. Create a new directory (or use existing Firebase project directory) and run the following command:

```
firebase init functions
```

Go through the setup and you'll get a directory structure similar to this (will be slightly different for Javascript and Typescript):

[image]

Then in your `index.ts` (or `.js`) file:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const firestoreTrigger = functions.firestore.document("/messages/{lastMessage}").onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const lastMessage = change.after.data().lastMessage;
    console.log(lastMessage);
    return;
});
```

You can write your functions in them. To deploy, run the `firebase deploy --only functions` command.

Comment: Really thank you for answering. so after running that command I added `import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';` in my index.js file and now this error is coming:  `Cannot use import statement outside a module`. Directory: [Image Link](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/736207678388305933/862675734462857216/unknown.png)

Comment: @HyperTechGamer please share a screenshot of your directory screenshot and where you are adding the code. Are you adding the code in the index.js file created by the firebase init command?

Comment: i was not coding in the file created by the command before. after seeing your comment i shifted the code to file created by that command. can you explain me how i can connect index.js to my html page? Directory Image: [link](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/736207678388305933/862679761335222292/unknown.png?width=837&height=430)

Comment: @HyperTechGamer you don't link Firestore triggers to your frontend. That function will deploy only when a document is updated in your Firestore database. You can use `.onCreate()` to run the function when a new document is created. I'd recommend you to watch this [firecast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk). Just deploy the functions and try adding a document in Firestore in that messages collection and update it. You can then see the log statement in the logs tab in the console.

Comment: actually what I am trying to do is: when firestore value will be updated, then js will add a element in html. I don't know maybe this is not the right way of making a chat app. I will try watching that firecast link! Thank you

Comment: @HyperTechGamer then I don't think you need a cloud function. But if my answer helped you, you can accept it and upvote it else feel free to ask further queries.